# How to access class level variables from inner object class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, branch.io

I am using branchSDK, It creates `Object` class inside the activity lcass. I need to access class level variables from this `object` class.

Following the inner object class, that branch created.

```
 object branchListener : Branch.BranchReferralInitListener {
        override fun onInitFinished(referringParams: JSONObject?, error: BranchError?) {
            if (error == null) {
                Log.i("BRANCH_SDK", referringParams.toString())

                if(referringParams?.has("news") ==true){

                }

            } else {
                Log.e("BRANCH_SDK", error.message)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Branch. From looking at their basic instructions [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration#section-initialize-branch) that are written in Java, the equivalent would be an anonymous object assigned to a property, which does have access to the outer class members:

```
val branchListener = object: Branch.BranchReferralInitListener {
    override fun onInitFinished(referringParams: JSONObject?, error: BranchError?) {
        if (error == null) {
            Log.i("BRANCH_SDK", referringParams.toString())

            if(referringParams?.has("news") == true){

            }

        } else {
            Log.e("BRANCH_SDK", error.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Presumably there is some function this listener can be passed to when you're making some kind of request, but it wasn't mentioned on this (the only page I read from their instructions).